# How do you read the userInfo of another user with Firebase's cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I had in mind to create a cloud function that let a user read some of the user infos of another user under certaine conditions.

For example:

```
const user1 = ??? // user1 is the current user
const user1Data = await firestore().collection('Users').doc('user1.uid').get()


const user2 = ??? // user2 is the user whith user2.uid == user1Data.partnerUid
const user2Data = await firestore().collection('Users').doc('user2.uid').get()

if (user1Data.partnerEmail == user2.email && user1Data.partnerEmail == user2.email) {
  // ...
  // the endpoint deliver some of the user2 data to user1.
  // ...
}
```

I have seen the documentation of Cloud functions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_

I have seen that with the admin API we can call getUser:
admin.auth().getUser(uid)

The difference between functions.auth() and admin.auth() is not clear for me. Can we call admin within cloud functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The difference between functions.auth() and admin.auth() is not clear for me.

When you import `functions` from firebase-functions, all that gets you is an SDK used for building the definition of functions for deployment.  It doesn't do anything else.  You can't access user data using `functions`.

When you import `admin` from firebase-admin, that gives you access to the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) that can actually [manage user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) in Firebase Authentication. You will want to use this to look up and modify users as needed, and it works just fine when running code in Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug !

Answer (score 1):

> The difference between functions.auth() and admin.auth() is not clear for me. Can we call admin within cloud functions ?

Basically `functions.auth()`, will let you trigger Cloud Functions in response to the creation and deletion of Firebase user accounts. For example, you could send a welcome email to a user who has just created an account in your app:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // ...
});
```

`functions.auth()` is from the cloud function package:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Using the above package you can preform firestore, database or auth triggers that will run in response to creating data in the database or creating a new user...

---

```
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

The firebase admin sdk is used to access the database from privileged environments example inside cloud functions.

Check the following links:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Comment: Since the answer helped you please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to it, thank you!